# separation in search result

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I'm new in django and python
I have view function which retrieve some data from database and show them on a page.
but there is a problem all the data are displayed on one page however i need a separation, It must be displayed 6 data on each page and if the number of data are more than 6 user can read them on the next page. i have no idiea how to do this

## my view is :

```
   def search1(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = SearchForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                cd = form.cleaned_data
                books=data(cd)
                return render_to_response('result.html', {'books': books, 'form': form})
        else:
            form = SearchForm()
        return render_to_response('form.html', {'form': form})
```

## my template:

```
    {% if books %}
    <p>Found {{ books|length }} book{{ books|pluralize }}.</p>
    <ul dir=rtl>
        {% for book in books %}
        <p>title:  {{ book.title }}</p>
        <p>price:  {{ book.price }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No books matched your search criteria.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look in to [django paginator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/?from=olddocs)

Answer (score -1):

I modify my code for using paginator but in result page when I click on next  it show my  search page again . what is the problem?
 view:

```
def search1(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    form = SearchForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        book_list=data(cd)
        paginator = Paginator(book_list, 6)
        page = request.GET.get("page", 1)
        try:
            books = paginator.page(page)
        except (PageNotAnInteger, TypeError):
            # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
            books = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
            books = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

        return render_to_response('list.html', {"books": books})
else:
    form = SearchForm()
    return render_to_response('form.html', {'form': form})
```

template :

```
    {% for book in books.object_list %}
    {# Each "contact" is a Contact model object. #}
    {{ book.full_name|upper }}<br />
    {{book.froshande}}
{% endfor %}

<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if books.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page={{ books.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ books.number }} of {{ books.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if books.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ books.next_page_number }}">next</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: You are calling the Paginator inside the POST block. Its a GET request which is why its reloading the SearchForm again